# How to validate Location Column in Sharepoint list?

Tags: list, if-statement, sharepoint, excel-formula

I need a conditional formula to validate data that is put in the location column to only accept valid street addresses. For instance, to prevent someone from putting an email address in the location column. The location column so far accepts the email address as a street address.

[Location column accepting an email address as a location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcXie.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following column validation to exclude string contains "@"

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",Address)),TRUE))
```

[image]